# GNU indent: does it support C++

Tags: c++, vim, indentation

I used [indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) to format my C code and it works very well.

Now I'm working with C++ and I still want to use indent. However, I find that it does not support the class declaration very well. Here is an example:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test ();
    void ttt ();
protected:
    virtual void func ();
};
```

This is a header file named `test.h` and after using indent like this: `export VERSION_CONTROL=never; indent -bli0 -blf -bls -nbfda -npsl -i4 -ts4 test.h`, it becomes as below:

```
class Test
{
  public:
        Test ();
        void ttt ();
  protected:
          virtual void func ();
};
```

As you see, before `public` and `protected`, two spaces are added and `virtual vodi func();` isn't aligned at all.

So indent doesn't support C++?

Comment: Possible cross dupe: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14959/setting-c-indentation-level

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's not a duplicate. This question is about GNU `indent`; that one is about `vim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GNU `indent` does not support C++.

Quoting section 1.12 of the [GNU indent manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/html_node/indent_15.html):

> While an attempt was made to get indent working for C++, it will not do a good job on any C++ source except the very simplest.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `indent` offers **very** limited support for `C++` code,

but
[**clang-format**](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#clangformat) will support `C++` and other langauges/code like `C/Java/JavaScript/JSON/Objective-C/Protobuf/C#`.